# How do I use user defined build settings with multiple Xcode Schemes with a localized InfoPlist.strings file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have a codebase that has five Xcode Schemes. Each codebase is the same but creates five slightly different apps based on which scheme is selected. I have `CFBundleDisplayName` set to `$(APP_NAME)`, which is a build setting that has five different names for my apps, depending on the selected Xcode Scheme.

[image]

In my `InfoPlists.strings` file for German, I have `"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Sammeln";` The problem is that I need the `InfoPlists.strings` file to also have five different names. Here's some pseudocode of what I wish I could do:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = $(DE_APP_NAME);
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I'm stuck with one name in German for all five apps because I can't assign it a user defined build setting like I can in the base `Info.plist`.

Does anyone out there know how to do this properly? I know my use case is not common, so creative options might need to be found here.

[image]

Comment: I would have made 5 targets instead of 5 (*2 because it's 1 debug, 1 release) schemes.

Comment: A bit late for that, but I see your point. Would making it five Targets instead solve my issue at all though?

Comment: It should, since in a target you can specify you own plist, and then your own localization. But in scheme too, but defining your own plist for each scheme (no "inheritance"?) For a target, you can specify the .strings per target. Maybe with the `xcconfig` can lie your solution?

Comment: Oh I see now in Build Settings, you are correct! I can use a custom Info.plist per scheme, which should allow me to have a custom InfoPlist.strings per scheme, which will solve my problem. I hate to have exact duplicate Info plists for no reason other than this, but it works for now. It would be nice to have some inheritance. Thank you for your help!